# Vagrant Cloud Vagrantfile

Tags: vagrant

I've uploaded a Vagrant box to Vagrant Cloud.  My box has some custom config, so I want to customize the Vagrantfile that is created with `vagrant init.`  The Vagrant documentation hasn't been much help.

I'm working around this by distributing the correct Vagrantfile, but I'd prefer for users to just init the box and get my custom Vagrantfile.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can package a Vagrantfile along with your box.

you can look at some common box like `ubuntu/trusty64` or `ubuntu/xenial64` which comes with their own Vagrantfile (you can review the Vagrantfile under the `~/.vagrant.d/boxes/<name>/<version>/<provider>/Vagrantfile`

You can read about [Vagrantfile load order and merging](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/#load-order-and-merging) : vagrant reads the Vagrantfile from the box at first and those params can be overridden by the main Vagrantfile from the project directory

In the old days, you would use the `vagrant package` command and there's still some good doc on https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/package.html

> A common misconception is that the `--vagrantfile` option will package a
>   Vagrantfile that is used when vagrant init is used with this box. This
>   is not the case. Instead, a Vagrantfile is loaded and read as part of
>   the Vagrant load process when the box is used. For more information,
>   read about the Vagrantfile load order.

Comment: Aha!  That explains it- I was building my box with Packer, and lo and behold there is a vagrantfile_template value to point to the Vagrantfile.  Thanks!